# Convert EditText to TextView Programatically?

Tags: android, kotlin

**What I Want**

I want to convert EditText into TextView programmatically.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputValue"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number" />
```

how can I convert the above `EditText` to below `TextView`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: you probably can't, better question is _why_ do you want this

Comment: Because I want to reuse the layout. I don't want to redesign everything just for EditText to TextView.

Comment: One thing you can do is that set text to edittext and disable the edittext so that user can't give any input using that editext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use 1 edittext and 1 Textview on same postion and hide them according to your need

   or
2. You can use `editText.setEnabled(false);`

Comment: Thank You So Much, That is exactly what I wanted. 2nd option perfectly worked for me.

Comment: this doesn't actually convert the edit text to a textview - you're either just using two, or disabling it, so the original question was just asked incorrectly and needed to do more research, as this is something which could have been easily found